# Unspecified field types

Tags: postgresql, text, types, field, unspecified

What is the code for “any unspecified field type is text” in sql?

I’ve tried using replace and I’ve searched multiple sites but I haven’t found a solution

Comment: depends on RDBMS you use, e.g. in PostgreSQL there is datatype text

Comment: i think datatype Text is specified in the standards

Comment: It’s PostgreSQL. Is there a specific code I should be writing? Right now when I try to create a table I get the error “Cannot read properties of undefined”

Comment: Please post your table (ddl) definition script. Also exactly what do you mean by *unspecified field type*.

Comment: Requirements:
Drop tables employee, contact, and address if they already exist
Any unspecified field type is text.
Create a table called employee with fields for id as int, fname, lname, age as int, hiredate as date.